# How can I pass all arguments to my callback function?

Tags: php

I have a function in my class which takes a callback function as an argument.

But I'd then like to pass ***n*** additional arguments to the callback:

```
$myClass->each(function($result,$arg1,$arg2,$arg3){

   echo $arg2; //expected: bar

},'foo','bar',85);
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
class myClass {

    public function each() {

        $callback = func_get_arg(0);
        $args = array_slice(func_get_args(), 1); //_____
                                                 //     |
        if (is_callable($callback)) {            //     |  I have $args
            foreach ($this->results as $result) {//     |  But how can I pass
                  $callback($result,...$args);   //     |  them to $callback
            }                     // ^                  |  as a set of args?
        }                         // |__________________| 
    }

}
```

please note I'm using php 5.4 so I can't use the `...` operator

Comment: just mod your callback to accept an array, then you can pass in the func_get_args() result directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is, I believe, `call_user_func_array`. I know it seems a bit archaic in the era of the splat operator, but I think it's the best option in 5.4.

```
public function each() {
    $callback = func_get_arg(0);
    $args = func_get_args();

    if (is_callable($callback)) {            
        foreach ($this->results as $result) {
              $args[0] = $result;
              call_user_func_array($callback, $args);
        }                  
    }                       
}
```

This simply overwrites the first item in `$args` (which we don't want anyway) with the appropriate `$result` value.